# How to send validation errors as JSON to view

Tags: php, laravel, api, validation, laravel-5.3

i'm building an API, i'm validating the input fields in my StoreLesson.php

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

i'm using `postman` to test the API, things are working fine but when i send POST request with empty fields, in `postman` console in webview i'm getting redirected to `welcom.blade.php`

```
//LessonController.php
public function store(StoreLessons $request) 
{
    Lesson::create($request->all());

    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);  //i'm not getting any json with errors

    //Lesson::create(input::all());

    return $this->respondCreated('Lesson created successfully');
}
```

i want to display (return) the validator error as json

thank You

Answer (score 1):

use the validator like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
if ($validator->fails())
    return response()->json($validator);
```

Comment: i got this error now `Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
Redirecting to http://localhost:8000.`

Comment: i think the same but i'm not getting any error response from validator tried many methods but keeps redirecting to home page, is there any way i can achieve this

Comment: check if the vidiation fails, if fails var_dump the $validator before return it.

Comment: i did the var_dump($validator); but still the same redirection, this is my api http://frocerie.in/Laravelapi/public/api/v1/lessons

Comment: I not get you idea, what's the relation between the api and the validator response in store

Comment: when user post new lesson i want to validate whether the input fields are empty, if empty i want to pass the validator errors to the view as json

Comment: if you want to use the validator, first make the rules

Comment: the rules are in Requests/StoreLessons.php `public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132476/discussion-between-mr-robot-and-kris-roofe).

Answer (score 0):

```
Create StoreLessons Request inside app/Http/Requests.And call this request in LessonController.php you did.

----------
     class StoreLessons extends Request
            {
                /**
                 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
                 *
                 * @return bool
                 */
                public function authorize()
                {
                    return true;
                }

                /**
                 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
                 *
                 * @return array
                 */
                public function rules()
                {
                     return [
                'title' => 'required',
                'body' => 'required',
            ];
                }


                /**
                 * @param array $errors
                 *
                 * @return JsonResponse
                 */
                public function response(array $errors)
                {
                    return response($errors);
                }

                /**
                 * @param Validator $validator
                 *
                 * @return mixed
                 */
                protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator)
                {
                    return $validator->errors()->all();
                }
```